# export JAVA_HOME permanently on debian

Tags: java, debian

I have tried to make the `JAVA_HOME` on Debian OS. But every time when I close the terminal and reopen, `echo $JAVA_HOME` doesn't work. I tried following process to make the path

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_71 
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
source ~/.bashrc
```

What's the mistake I'm doing? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running export from inside a terminal is not persistent after the end of that session. You need to open your ~/.bashrc file in a text editor and add the two lines at the end of that file, then when you run the source command (or any time a new terminal session is instantiated), the .bashrc file is evaluated and the export statements come into effect.

Comment: You do what you're already doing, but the export lines go INTO the .bashrc file. Open it in an editor, put them in there, then source it (or start a new terminal session which will automatically source it on startup).

Comment: This is the path for my `~/.bashrc` file I could find
`/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh` and I opened it using `gedit` and paste the above mentioned 2 lines at the end of the document. But it didn't work

Comment: It's in your home directory. It's a hidden file, just enter the following in a terminal `gedit ~/.bashrc`. Then edit the file and save it.